How to place on a caption on a code-generated figure in Markdown
The answers I have seen for figure captions assume you're inserting an image file.  In my case I'm generating a plot with code and would like to be able to put a caption on it.
I'm working in R Studio but the code itself is Python.  Using Pandoc to ultimately generate a pdf.
So if I have this code chunk
```{python residual_predicted_plot, echo=FALSE}
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,3))
sns.scatterplot(x=model3.predict(), y=model3.resid, ax=ax)
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ax.axvline(x=xlim[0] + 1/3*(xlim[1]-xlim[0]), color='orchid', linestyle='--')
ax.axvline(x=xlim[0] + 2/3*(xlim[1]-xlim[0]), color='orchid', linestyle='--')
ax.axhline(y=0, color='orchid', linestyle='--')
ax.set_xlabel('$\hat{y}$')
ax.set_ylabel('$\epsilon$')
ax.set_title('Residual vs. Predicted Scatterplot')

plt.show()
```

It produces this plot

How can I get a caption associated with it?

This is a markdown question, not a matplotlib question.

You're using R Markdown and Python together, which is an unusual combination.  You should include a complete working example, because the R Markdown folks like me don't know how to get Python to produce a plot, and the Python folks mostly don't know how R Markdown works.

Finally figured out how to draw a plot.  As you'd expect, the chunk option fig.cap = "some caption" works just fine in a Python code chunk.

They closed this question or I'd say submit that as an answer...

I think you chose the wrong tags.  I've just edited them, but that probably won't be enough to get you reopened.  I did vote to close because your example isn't reproducible.  If you want it reopened, you could fix that, and it would probably happen.  But if my comment is an answer that's good enough, don't waste your time on SO nonsense.

@KJ:  This question might be answered by the dup you cited, but that question and its answers are awfully unfocussed.

I would recommend saving the figure as an image with the matplotlib.pyplot.savefig function. Then captioning it as an image. But if you want the caption contained within the generated plot you can use matplotlib.pyplot.text
Some relevant links:

plt.text
plt.text examples
Similar question

